# Cleaning a multiple checkbox field into a bitwise operation output in django?

Tags: python, django, checkbox, bit-manipulation

I currently have a multiple checkbox field in my form that I would like to clean into just being an interger that I could eventually use in bitwise operations however I'm unsure how I return that number back from the cleaned data into my .save().

So far I have come up with:

```
def clean_checkbox(self):
        checkList = self.cleaned_data.getlist('checkbox')
        contentType = 0
        if not checkList:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select at least one content type.")
        if 'Image' in checkList:
            contentType|1
        if 'Video' in checkList:
            contentType|2
        if 'Media' in checkList:
            contentType|4
        if 'Text' in checkList:
            contentType|8
        return contentType
```

In the initalization code of the variable checkList (`checkList = self.cleaned_data.getlist('checkbox')`). How can I get a list from the cleaned data to iterate through so that I can do bitwise operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `contentType|8` is only doing a logical or, and not assigning it into anything.

Either assign the value back into `contentType`:

```
contentType = contentType|8
```

or use the unary version (much like increment `+=`) like so:

```
contentType |= 8
```

do this for each comparison, and then return this from your function.

Comment: Oh thanks. Do you have any idea how get the list from the request.POST in order to be cleaned? `self.cleaned_data.getlist('checkbox')` doesn't do the job.

/ Do you know how to get the cleaned field out of being bound to the model form. Like the equivalent of doing request.POST['checkbox'] except it would be something like boundForm['checkbox']?